# Double color navbar fixed top bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i want recreate this image:

[image]

in a `navbar-fixed-top` using `Bootstrap`, at the moment i have add this custom `CSS`:

**navbar-fixed-top.css**

```
.navbar {
    background-color: #8CB5A0;
    background-image: none;
}
```

and this is the bootstrap code of the navbar:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only"> Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project Name</a>   
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is the css:

but how i can add the double red border, because there are two type of red, or better i can add directly the image as background?

Comment: Adding the image as a background would be as easy as `background: url("urltoimage") repeat-x;`

Comment: add `border-bottom:4px ridge red;` css rule to your `.navbar` class, if you don't want to use image.

Comment: i have use the image as @mituw16 suggest and works!

Comment: Great! Glad we could be of help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the image  a background like so  `background: url("urltoimage") repeat-x;`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a better option making use of `box-shadow`

[Double border](http://jsfiddle.net/vRbW7/)

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: nice, never seen box shadow used like that +1!

Comment: Thanks! One thing to add is that the box shadow will not affect other elements, so you may need to adjust some margins for items below the double border.

Comment: Interesting solution, I like that @cclark413 .